# SQL min value on join tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, spatial

Consider tables `nyc_streets` and `nyc_subway_stations` with columns `name` nad `geom`.
For three certain streets I want to find 10 closest metro stations with `ST_Distance` function.
I tried to start with this, but failed:

```
SELECT street.name, subway.name
FROM nyc_streets AS street INNER JOIN nyc_subway_stations AS subway 
HAVING ST_Distance(street.geom, subway.geom) == min(ST_Distance(street.geom, subway.geom))
AND street.name in ('Elder Ave', 'Castle Hill Ave', '4th Ave')
GROUP BY street.name, subway.name ORDER BY subway.name;
```

How to approach this problem?

Comment: No SELECT ? Full query text please.

Comment: @Serg formatting error, sorry, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Order by distance with a `row_number()`, select top 10. Assuming `id` is a PK of `street`

```
SELECT street_name, subway_name
FROM (
    SELECT street.name street_name, subway.name subway_name
      , row_number() over(partition by street.id order by ST_Distance(street.geom, subway.geom)) rn
    FROM nyc_streets AS street 
    CROSS JOIN nyc_subway_stations AS subway 
    WHERE street.name in ('Elder Ave', 'Castle Hill Ave', '4th Ave')
) t
WHERE rn <= 10
```

Comment: This works, but returns more than 10 stations -- any ideas for a fix?